# How long will this take to reach.. kimye?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found the [1bc29b36f623ba8](https://twitter.com/1bc29b36f623ba8) twitter account on 4chan last night, it's a user who is posting md5 hashes every 10 minutes in a sequential order, starting at `!` and I assume with no end in sight.

The twitter account has a specific twitter post structure

`[sequence hashed] #[sequence in plaintext] #md5 #allday #`

which in my eyes reads quite upbeat about performing md5 hashing *all day*.

The most interesting thing, I think, is that this crypto focused account is following a rather odd selection of users. *Kim Kardashian* and *Kanye West*.

Could someone do the math and figure out when it will reach `kimye`? (*kimye* is a common abbreviation of Kim Kardashian and Kanye West, as a couple).. I'm barely interested in the couple, but from what I can tell `kimye` will be the first string to reference the accounts two favourite people.

The characters used appear to be limited to the following:

```
!#$%&()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Comment: Definitely the strangest question I have ever seen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are $91$ characters available, in the order

```
!#$%&()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

The number of tweets to get to $\texttt{kimye}$ is
$$\begin{align*}
\hphantom{+}91^{1} & \quad \text{(number of 1-character strings)} \\\\
{}+ 91^2 & \quad \text{(number of 2-character strings)}\\\\
{}+ 91^3 & \quad \text{(number of 3-character strings)}\\\\
{}+ 91^4 & \quad \text{(number of 4-character strings)}\\\\
{}+ 71\cdot91^4 & \quad \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{\text{number of 5-character strings}}{\text{starting with a character before }\texttt{k}}\\\\
{}+ 69\cdot91^3 & \quad \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{\text{number of 5-character strings}}{\text{starting with }\texttt{k}\text{ but whose 2nd character is before }\texttt{i}}\\\\
{}+ 73\cdot91^2 & \quad \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{\text{number of 5-character strings}}{\text{starting with }\texttt{ki}\text{ but whose 3rd character is before }\texttt{m}}\\\\
{}+ 85\cdot91^1 & \quad \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{\text{number of 5-character strings}}{\text{starting with }\texttt{kim}\text{ but whose 4th character is before }\texttt{y}}\\\\
{}+ 65\cdot91^0 & \quad \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{\text{number of 5-character strings}}{\text{starting with }\texttt{kimy}\text{ but whose 5th character is before }\texttt{e}}
\end{align*}$$
which makes for a total of
$$4,990,767,847\;\text{ tweets}$$
before $\texttt{kimye}$. At a rate of $6\text{ tweets/hour}$, from the inception of the Twitter feed, it will take about
$$831,794,641 \text{ hours}\approx 94,891\text{ years}$$
to get to the string $\texttt{kimye}$.

Comment: That's not what I get using the [conversion algorithm for bijective base-$91$ numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#Definition). Might you have miscounted somewhere?

Comment: @r.e.s.: I'm pretty sure it's correct now (after all it agrees with your answer). I suspect you're getting off by $3$ because I also had some issues with the characters `<=>` not showing up because the website was trying to parse them as an HTML tag, but copying the relevant strings into a character counter seems to support the numbers presently indicated in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I think it's okay now.

Comment: thankyou @ZevChonoles, slightly disappointed I won't get to see it.

Answer (score 8):

The $91$ characters in the order given, i.e.,

```
 !#$%&()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

will serve as the digits of a [bijective base-91 numeration system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration). Counting in this system is the same as listing the digit-strings in [shortlex order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order):

```
decimal     bijective base-91
----------  -----------------
1           !
2           #
3           $
...
91          /
92          !!
93          !#
...
4990767847  kimyd
4990767848  kimye   <---
4990767849  kimyf
...
```

Here's an implementation of the conversion algorithm given at the Wikipedia link:

```
def word_to_number(w, alphabet):
    """
    return the integer n such that w is the nth word
    in the shortlex ordering of words on the given alphabet string 
    """
    k = len(alphabet)
    n = q = 0
    for c in w[::-1]:
        p = alphabet.index(c) + 1
        n = n + p*(k**q)
        q = q + 1
    return n
```

Then

```
alph = "!#$%&()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
print word_to_number('kimye', alph)
```

gives the result

```
4990767848
```

i.e., 'kimye' is the 4,990,767,848-th word in the listing by shortlex order.

---

For reference, and as a cross-check, here's the inverse function:

```
def number_to_word(n, alphabet):
    """
    return the nth word (n >= 0) 
    in the shortlex ordering of words on the given alphabet string
    """
    k = len(alphabet)
    word = ''
    q = n
    while q > 0:
        word = alphabet[(q-1)%k] + word
        q = (q-1)//k
    return word
```

Then `number_to_word(4990767848, alph)  -->  kimye`.

Comment: I think the code is correct. E.g., I also programmed the inverse conversion and it finds 'kimye' from the input $4990767848$.

Comment: Ah, I typed the sum into wolfram alpha incorrectly :) My answer agrees with yours now.

Comment: thankyou @r.e.s., I didn't know about bijective numerations until now - very interesting stuff, I greatly appreciate the effort.